# Pythagorean theorem for functions

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

If $u$ and $v$ are functions on a function space, what is an easy way to see that Pythagorean holds for functions as it does for triangles:

> Suppose u and v are orthogonal functions in V. Then
>   $\|u+v\|^{2}=\|u\|^{2}+\|v\|^{2}$

This is used later to prove for minimization criteria for orthogonal spaces:

> Suppose U is a finite-dimensional subspace of V. Then two vectors u and v.
>
> Then $\left\|v-P_{U} v\right\| \leq\|v-u\|$
>
> Furthermore, the
>   inequality above is an equality if and only if $u=P_{U} v$

where $P_{U} v$ is the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto subspace of U

Comment: Use the inner product definition for that function space and the fact that $\|u\|^2=\langle u,u \rangle$.

Comment: @Azif00 the question is in the first line: "what is an easy…"

Comment: I wouldn't say it holds *for triangles* nor *for functions* but rather it holds *for inner product spaces*, making the question moot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for any *orthogonal vectors* $x$ and $y$ in a inner product space $( \textsf V , \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle )$ the equality 
$$\| x+y \|^2 = \| x \|^2 + \| y \|^2$$
is still true and the proof is the following :

$$\begin{align} 
\| x+y \|^2 &= \langle x+y,x+y \rangle \\
&= \langle x,x+y \rangle + \langle y,x+y \rangle \\
&= \langle x,x \rangle + \langle x,y \rangle + \langle y,x \rangle  +\langle y,y \rangle \\
&= \langle x,x \rangle + \langle y,y \rangle \\
&= \| x \|^2 + \| y \|^2
\end{align}$$
*Note* : $\langle x,y \rangle = \langle y,x \rangle =0$ by definition since $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal.

Answer (score 3):

By linearity ad distributivity (two properties of any linear vector space) we have
$$
||u+v||^2 \equiv \left< (u+v), (u+v)  \right>
= \left< u, u  \right> + \left< u, v \right> + \left< v,u  \right> + \left< v, v  \right>
=||u||^2 +||v||^2 + \left< u, v \right> + \left< v,u  \right> 
$$
and since $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal, by definition the last two terms are zero.